# Split Xbox One to two TVs

Tags: xbox-one

What is the best way to split screen my Xbox One to two different TVs?  Can you play 2/3/4 split screen games on two TVs without all players duplicated in both screens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

unfortunately you cannot do this. You can split the signal with HDMI splitter (which mirrors the image), but it will be completely duplicated. You need two Xboxes if you want to display two players' screens in two different TVs.

If your TV includes a zoom function, you can sort of do it by zooming to the desired player's screen, but it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: I don't want to Accept this answer, but unfortunately you're totally right, I haven't been able to figure out how to do it and can't find a way to do it anywhere :-(  Maybe next version will have it...  
(I'm marking this the Accepted answer, thanks for your input!)

Comment: Yes, I know the struggle. There's currently no smart way to accomplish what you want, sorry. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a passive 3D TV, you can do it with one TV! For example, "Dual Play" is built by LG to give you full-screen mode instead of split-screen (I think only LG has passive 3D TVs! But I'm not sure :D)
There is an instruction here on how to do it:
https://www.tweaking4all.com/video/gaming/split-screen-game-full-screen/